# Maven dependency resolve and package in docker

Tags: maven, docker

In my Docker file, I have these two commands for my spring boot maven project,

```
COPY ./pom.xml .
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml dependency:resolve
COPY ./ .
RUN mvn -B -f ./pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true package
```

My purpose was to download all the dependencies in the pom first and then compile the source code and pack it in the second step. But I can see many downloads happening in the second phase also.

My question is why there are downloads happening after the dependency resolution.

Comment: Plugins probably. Some plugins dependencies are downloaded (or updated) when the plugin runs. If your build steps call these plugins - they might get downloaded. These are probably not application dependencies.